# Error moving video file while it has no flaws

Tags: windows, video

I've a video file which is complete and it plays without any flaws but when I want to move it to another folder, I face with this error:

> The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
>           0 file(s) moved.

Why does this error occurs though my video has no error when played?

The file is on drive C and I can move the file within this drive but no other drive!

Comment: Seems like the destination location may be corrupt? Scandisk/f may help. Or, try and copy the video to a different place and see if it works (or not)

Comment: I've tried it, but same as before.

Comment: the file is on drive C and I can move the file within this drive but no other drive! 18% of the file can be moved(or copied) but then the error occurs.\

Comment: Hang on. What if you copy a different file to the 'other' drive? Sounds like the other drive is naff!

Comment: @DaveRook ,I can copy to other drives without any problem.but the for this file the error occurs

Comment: How big is the file? How many other drives do you have? Can you run a SMART tool on the other drives please

Comment: the file is 346MB, I've for drives which all have at least 20GB free space. I don't know what you mean by SMART tool? .

Comment: Google SMART tool, and use it on all your hard drives :)

Answer (score 1):

There can be 2 problems here.

1. It cannot move the file because it cannot write to the destination (rights issue or others)
2. It cannot remove the source file because it is in use or due to rights issues.

I would advice to copy the movie to the new destination. If it copies, the problem is 2, if it can't copy, the problem is 1.

Once you have established which one it is, troubleshoot that problem. If it cannot remove the file, one of the things I've seen is that the little preview in windows explorer sometimes locks the file while it reads the file. Click the file and wait for it to load before trying to delete it. (eg. wait 5 minutes) Alternatively, disable the preview.

Comment: none of them! I've access right and it's not in use in any other program.also I can delete the file! maybe it is useful to say that I've downloaded the file with Idm(so maybe it has been corrupted but why I can play it?!!)

Comment: None of them, as in: You cannot copy the file to the destination? Which means there is a problem at the destination. It is possible IDM's preview functionality keeps the file locked. Can you close IDM completely and try it again?

Comment: yet the same problem(closing IDM completely)! I've change suffix of it(.mp4) to .txt , compressed it , but all failed.

Comment: And it only happens with this file? Can you try redownloading it? The file might've been written to a sector that became corrupted.